# How to write setup.py to produce generic .whl package

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, swig, setuptools

I am writing setup.py for my [small python package](https://github.com/Zhylkaaa/maca_analyse), which is python wrapper on c++ tool, and it's depends on shared libraries like icu-uc, boost_program_options, and some custom ones. Python wrapper build with `swig`. I use `Extension(libraries=[...])` to specify libraries to link.

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
package_name = Extension(
    name='_package_name',
    sources=['some_souces.cpp',
            'some_swig_interfaces.i'
    ],
    swig_opts=['-c++'],
    libraries=['icuuc', ...],
)
setup(
    name='package_name',
    version='0.1.0',
        ....
    ext_modules=[package_name],
    py_modules=['package_name']
)
```

and I build this with `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`

And when I build and install generated file locally it works fine, but when I truing to use `pip3 install package_name.whl` on computer with other version of icu-uc or other libraries it's crashes at runtime throwing `ImportError: libicuuc.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. So basically my question is how to build more generic `.whl` package that don't stick to library version but looks for any match?